# CSS Level 4 hex rgb hsl lch etc value checking via Regex

Tags: css, regex, colors

```
^(#[0-9a-f]{3}|#(?:[0-9a-f]{2}){2,4}|(rgb|hsl)a?\((-?\d+%?[,\s]+){2,3}\s*[\d\.]+%?\))$
```

I use this regex previously but Now Spec changes and rgb support space separated systax as well as (/20%) for alpha value. I'm not good with regex. So, Can anyone help me with it ?
Which support the new format and also lch and cmyk format support.

Comment: In order to get help, please help us by providing samples for input and output

Comment: I already provided the previous regex i use which support syntax like `rgba(20, 30, 100, .3)` but I need this as well as the new css color level 4 syntax support , like `rgb(20 30 100 / 20%)` . That's it.

Comment: @susanta96 we need more examples than just `rgba(20, 30, 100, .3)` and `rgb(20 30 100 / 20%)`, u also mentioned lch and cmyk but no examples for them??

Answer (score 2):

Not a well-formed and thought-out question but this regex should suffice in answering the question and be enough for what you need:

`(?:(rgba?|hsla?|lch|lab|cmyk)\((\-?\s*\d*\.?\d*\s*(?:[\%]|deg)?)\s*\,?\s*(\-?\s*\d*\.?\d*\s*(?:[\%]|deg)?)\s*\,?\s*(\-?\s*\d*\.?\d*\s*(?:[\%]|deg)?)\s*[\,\/]?\s*(\-?\s*\d*\.?\d*\s*(?:[\%]|deg)?)\)|\#[\da-fA-F]{6}|\#[\da-fA-F]{3})`

Comment: test this [here](https://regex101.com/r/xq3Tae/1)